# bash check between times - conditional gives "not found"

Tags: bash

I have the following code which provides the corresponding error below it.

```
#!/bin/sh

H=$(date +%H)
# If during sleeping hours (23 [or 11 pm] to 8 am), *don't* turn on the lights
night_time=8
wake_up_time=23 
if (( $H -le $night_time -o $H -le $wake_up_time )); then 
    # Bedtime
    echo "You need to go to bed"
else
    echo "You're probably awake"
fi
```

**Error:**

```
/file_location/file.sh: 7: /file_location/file.sh 11: not found
```

so it appears that I have problems with the conditional.

---

What could be causing this error?  I have added spaces between the `((`,`))` and test, and I made them arithmetic parenthesis `(` instead of the brackets `[` or `test` command since I am dealing with numbers.

What else could I be missing?

Comment: Change (( and )) to [ ].

Comment: You've got your time limits wrong for a programmer; replace 23 with 1, and 8 with 5.  You've got caffeine to keep you going!  (Of course, you also have to check the rest of the comparison logic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either test or arithmetic evaluation, but do not mix them up.

Using test:

```
if [ "$H" -le "$night_time" -o "$H" -ge "$wake_up_time" ];
```

Using arithmetic evaluation:

```
if (( "$H" <= "$night_time" || "$H" >= "$wake_up_time" ));
```

And you used "less or equal" two times, the second should probably be "greater or equals".